# PHP placement problem

Tags: php, function

I am calling this function halfway down the page:

```
    <div id="leftArea">
        <?php
        if (isset($id)){
            single($id);
        }
        ?>
    </div>
```

The problem is i want use some of the output in the meta tags in the `<head>`, whats the best way to approach this?

EDIT:

The single function, takes the $id and echo's the data straight to the page, exactly where it is. In the DIV leftArea. But i want to take one of the rows from the DB and insert it into the META tags at the top

Comment: We'll need to see more of your code.

Comment: not sure what you are asking can you show us more code that's related to the `<head>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the code into the `<head>` section.

Comment: But then surely it will echo the output into the head section. I only need one value from the function, not the entire output

Comment: Write a new function that only outputs the one value you want, and place the call to that function in <head>?

Answer (score 1):

**Redesign your System**

The best method is to create a class that manages your html page for you, example:

```
$Page = new HTMLPage("My Page",HTMLPage::Strict);

$Page->addScript("....");
$Page->addScript("....");
$Page->addScript("....");

$Page->addStyle("....");
$Page->addStyle("....");
$Page->addStyle("....");

$Page->SetBody($MyTemplate);

$Page->send();
```

this way though out your functions you can do

```
function myfunc()
{
    global $Page;
    $Page->addScript("....");
}
```

the main point here is you should build your document up before sending it to the browser, this way you still have control over the content no matter where your code is executing from.

on the final send method you build your content up, and then push the content via echo, and then exit directly. (all processing should be done prior to output to manage errors)